# how can i ssh into a server, and read a pid file and bring back the #?

Tags: perl, ssh, pid

i am tasked with Perl to ssh into another server and stop/start/restart the process if it is not already started.

i will break this down into small chunks:

::how can i ssh into a server, and read a pid file and bring back the #?::

i can do this: system("ssh serverid.gcsc.att.com -l myid -i /home/myid/.ssh/authorized_keys 'kill -9 1234'"); just fine, kill the process after authenticating into the server.

but how do i read a pid file/any file on that server, and get the value into a variable so that i can then ssh and kill the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is with backticks.

```
 my $output = `ssh server -l myid -i /home/myid/.ssh/authorized_keys some_command`;
```

`$output` will contain the output of your `ssh` command.

Comment: oh man, subtle but spot on, you! ***everything*** between the back ticks. sheeze. THANK YOU!! one nano step at a time. ["i'll beeee baaaack"]

    my $output = `ssh server.acme.com -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys less tail_myuid.pid`;
    print $output . "\n";

puts into $output contents, "1234".